# Spring Boot and constructor injection

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, yaml, inversion-of-control

I'm building a new Springboot application, and I'm a bit confused about constructor injection for properties. I'm reading values from a yaml file.  And the yaml looks like this:

```
app:
  name: myApplication
  jdbc:
      jdbcUrl: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MyDb"
      driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
      maximumPoolSize: 1
      username: domainmanager
      password: password
```

This is being read into two objects, once which processes the name and the jdbc data is held into a second object.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class AppConfig {
    private String name;
    private DataSourceInfo jdbc;
```

If I use setter based injection everything seems to work perfectly. But I'd really like to use constructor injection but when I add this constructor:

```
    public AppConfig(    @Value("name") String name,
                         @Value("jdbc") DataSourceInfo dsInfo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.jdbc = dsInfo;
    }
```

Gives me this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.ecomm.properties.DataSourceInfo': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

The DataSourceInfo class is annotated like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "jdbc")
public class DataSourceInfo {
    private String jdbcUrl;
    private String driverClassName;
    private String maximumPoolSize;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String type;
```

What am I missing? How do I convince the inversion of control container that it needs to inject an object and not a try to convert a string to an object? Is that even what's happening?

Comment: Note that you normally shouldn't combine `@Configuration` and `@ConfigurationProperties` on the same class; the latter is a pure "record object".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `@ConstructorBinding` annotation.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
@ConstructorBinding
public class AppConfig {
    private String name;
    private DataSourceInfo jdbc;
    public AppConfig(String name, DataSourceInfo jdbc) {
        this.name = name;
        this.jdbc = jdbc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, even I didn't know about that one; it's new in 2.2. Excellent.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- that makes two of us.

Comment: Hold on, though... this is about _how to use constructor injection for an `@ConfigurationProperties` class_, which isn't actually what OP needs.

Comment: So while the @ConstructorBinding has to be there, the other thing that wasn't obvious to me at first was that I needed to change the name of the parameter on the constructor to jdbc from dsInfo.  Apparently spring uses the parameter name and not the name of the attribute as the key for doing the setting. Good to know.

Comment: @TonyGiaccone Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes, it did work for me once I realized that I had to change the name on the constructor signature. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TonyGiaccone Happy to help.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `@Value`, it must have the form: `@Value("app.name") String name`; but you do not want to use it anyway. Spring favors `@ConfigurationProperties` for a long time now, and `@Value` does not work with relaxed binding either.

Answer (score 0):

Unmitigated provided a one-line answer, but the traditional mechanism (or one that simply avoids any Spring coupling at all with the implementation class) is to use an `@Bean` method in an `@Configuration` class, where you pass the properties object as a parameter and "unwind" it in the service's constructor:

```
@Bean
MyService(MyProperties props) {
  return new MyServiceImpl(props.getFoo(), props.getBar());
}
```

Note that your `jdbc` bits seem to duplicate the out-of-the-box auto-configuration for JDBC; prefer the defaults when practical.

Comment: Yes, well I'm not using the standard spring jdbc/db configuration, but instead spinning up a different orm, so that's why the jdbc stuff is there.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, and I understand your suggestion to avoid coupling with the Spring Framework. However, we've made a choice to use spring-boot for all our subsequent projects, and the coupling of our code to their capabilities far exceeds the setting of configuration. I'd like to be more vendor neutral, but it's a double edged sword. If we're going to use this framework we might as well make the best use of it.

Comment: @TonyGiaccone Then I recommend examining how Spring Boot itself handles things. Specifically, `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` is a great starting point for seeing what options are available.